# Test Failing after upgrade from 0.2.7 to 0.6.1

Tags: karate

After upgrading from 0.2.7 to 0.6.1, I am seeing a test failure when running from gradle.

The failing test is a simple:

```
And match response.dispositionInstructions == "Disposition Instructions"
```

When I run from intellij, the test passes.
Running from gradle, the following is logged:

```
15:11:22.840 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]     com.intuit.karate.exception.KarateException: path: $.dispositionInstructions, actual: '{"dispositionInstructions":"Disposition Instructions",  rest of document omitted}’ , expected: 'Disposition Instructions', reason: not equal
```

Not sure if it is relevant, but the JSON document is over 94k long.
However, if I paste the document (from the log) into a JSON validator (jsonlint.com), it shows it as being valid.

I am keen to exploit the new functionality and this is the only issue blocking me.
Any suggestions as to why this is failing on 0.6.1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dev of Karate here. Thanks for the clear explanation of the issue !

My guess is that this is related to this particular issue: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/144

Unfortunately, the person who logged that issue never reverted. I really hope that the suggested tweak to the surefire plugin to set the `file.encoding` does the trick.

Else do log an issue and cross-refer the above issue so that a notification goes out to the OP for that one.  With your help I can hopefully finally replicate this issue, and I may need your help to create a fake large payload that can simulate this problem in my local environment.

Comment: Many thanks for the quick response. As advised, addressed the problem by adding 'test { jvmArgs != "-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8"' to build.gradle.